# How to check the duplicate item in cart in angular 5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I am a newbie in angular 5 and I am making a simple cart to learn angular 5. I am stuck in a situation that I am confuse that How to check the duplicate entry in the cart data. Actually the problem is that I am confuse about should I store objects in array or array in objects to store data.

This is what I am doing
Home component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    items: Array<object> = [];
    total_items:Number = 0;
    cart = {};
    broadcast_obj = {items:[],totals:{}};
    total_sum:Number = 0.0;
    htmlToAdd:String = '';

    constructor(private _data: DataService) {  }

    ngOnInit() {
        //this.items_count = this.cart.length;
        this._data.cast.subscribe(res => this.broadcast_obj = res);
        this._data.changeCart(this.broadcast_obj);
    }

    additem(id,itemText,amount){
        this.total_items = 10;
        this.total_sum += amount;

        this.cart = {id:id, name: itemText, price: amount,quantity:1};
        if(this.items.length>0){
            this.items.find(x => x.id == 3);//error id does not exist on type object
        }
        this.items.push(this.cart);
        this.broadcast_obj.items = this.items;
        this.broadcast_obj.totals = {total_items:this.total_items,total_sum:this.total_sum};
        console.log(this.broadcast_obj)
        //this._data.changeCart(this.broadcast_obj);
    }

}
```

I am storing data in 2 objects and pushing them into array
1- {id:id, name: itemText, price: amount,quantity:1};
2- {total_items:this.total_items,total_sum:this.total_sum};

Now I want to check if id exists then increase the quantity but I am confuse am i doing right because I am searching for id in the array object and it is showing error as show in comment(id does not exist on type object).

Here is the current structure of array of objects
[image]

I was also thinking that If I store objects in array indexes of their ids like 
if item id=199 then I store object in array index[199] so that I can quickly search any item in the array.

I still dont know which approach is better as of searching point of view or both are wrong.

Please resolve my error as well as help me to store cart data in correct structure so that I can search item quickly and also pass cart data in observable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error because of this line: `items: Array<object> = [];` This liine says that `items` is an array of Objects (javascript objects). Objects don't have properties like id. You need to create an interface for you item:

```
interface ICartItem {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    price: number;
    quantity: number;
}
```

Then in your component you can do `items: ICartItem[] = [];` (same as `items: Array<ICartItem> = [];`) This will make the error go away.

Your component:

```
// ...
items: ICartItem[] = [];
cart: ICartItem; // no need to initialise it with empty object
//...
```

Comment: Or just run with `items: Array<any> = new Array<any>();`

Comment: @BorisLobanov thanks for answer. Where should I put interface because when I put it in component the whole class is full of erros.

Comment: you can out it in a separate file and import (just add `export` before declaring the interface) or put it above or below your class/component

Comment: @BorisLobanov now this line is red 
this.items.push(this.cart);
Error:
argument of type{} is not assignable to type icartItem

Comment: @BorisLobanov i have also written your code 

items: Array<ICartItem> = [ ]; but still the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165524/discussion-between-boris-lobanov-and-dev).

Comment: `any` is good for API data because you may receive 100 values, but only want to use 4. Instead of having to create a class to encapsulate 100 properties, just use `any`.

Comment: I agree that it's one of the rare use cases for any. However, in this situation I feel that an interface is definitely the way to go.

Comment: I decided to add an answer which uses `any` as a secondary approach.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the accepted answer from `@BorisLobanov`, I just thought that I would add a second example of how else you could achieve this...

By defining `items` as: `items: Array<any> = new Array<any>();` You will also mitigate these errors.

However as stated by `@BorisLobanov`, of which I agree ,note that:

> Using any is not a very good practice, it makes Typescript kinda pointless

---

... In my opinion one place where you would use an array of type `any` is when the "items" are being derived from an API call. The reason for this is that you may receive an array of objects which contain say 100 properties. However you only want to use 4 of the properties... or for the example shown below where you need the data to reach a certain value, but don't actually care about the data itself.

The use of `any` prevents the typescript compiler (no errors at compile time) from verifying the type structure of `items`, which in turn will allow you to `unsafely` access properties you know will exist.

---

The benefit is definitely apparent when the data structure has nested objects, for example:

```
australianCities = [
  {
    name: 'Sydney',
    suburbs: [{
      name: 'town 1',
      houses: [{
          population: 3,
          address: 'aa'
        },
        {
          population: 1,
          address: 'bb'
        }
      ]
    }]
  }, ...
];
```

It already hurts my soul to think about defining all these interfaces for every object here (imagine one which is actually complex), especially when API's can change, if all I want to do **sum the total population** in all the cities in Australia.

However this can be way less cumbersome by using `any`... something like:

```
let sum = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
population = australianCities.map(city => city.towns.map(town => town.houses.map(house => house.population).reduce(sum)).reduce(sum)).reduce(sum);
```

```js
var australianCities = [{
    name: 'Sydney',
    suburbs: [{
      name: 'town 1',
      houses: [{
          population: 3,
          address: 'aa'
        },
        {
          population: 1,
          address: 'bb'
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    name: 'Perth',
    suburbs: [{
      name: 'town 1',
      houses: [{
          population: 10,
          address: 'aa'
        },
        {
          population: 2,
          address: 'bb'
        }
      ]
    }]
  }
];

var sum = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;

totalPopulation = australianCities.map(city => city.suburbs.map(town => town.houses.map(house => house.population).reduce(sum)).reduce(sum)).reduce(sum);

console.log({
  totalPopulation
});
```